segmentation fault when trying to import the following packages: datasets, transformers, and evaluate
This is my first time posting on Stack overflow so I apologize if I didn't include enough detail
I am trying to finetune a Bert model from HuggingFace, and when I try the following import statements:
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer
import numpy as np
import evaluate

I get a segmentation fault.
I managed to isolate the segmentation fault to
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import Trainer
import evaluate

The import statements work on my Macbook Air M1 running python 3.11, but they give the segmentation fault when I run the exact same thing on my iMac with intel core i5 running python 3.12.4. I suspect it might be a compatibility issue, so I tried a downgraded python version 3.11 and reinstalling all the packages, but it still didn't work.
Thank you!

So I think the problem ended up being a compatibility issue between the intel based iMac and the packages I was using. I tried it on a third, seperate M2 based Macbook pro and it worked perfectly normally.
